# What Error Shall We handle in Using Sockets

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp, udp

When using non-blocking sockets to communicate with clients, what error codes we must care and do something other than calling close() directly? Can anyone list them and give a few comments about what extra work we must do?

Currently we only handle the EAGAIN and EWOULDBLOCK, for all the other errors we just close the socket. Is this kind of socket exception routine enough for a server software?

Answer (score 0):

I think you've mostly got it right.  There are two other transient errors that my code retries on rather than closing the socket, they are:

EINTR - this can be returned if the system call was interrupted by delivery of a signal.  The usual appropriate response is to try the system call again.  (See [here](http://blog.reverberate.org/2011/04/eintr-and-pc-loser-ing-is-better-case.html) for details on why this can occur)

ENOBUFS - Under certain circumstances, send() can return this if the network interface's output queue is full.  (yes, you'd expect send() to return EWOULDBLOCK or EAGAIN instead, but I have seen this returned)